# How to find and match data between columns and put in a new column in sql?

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I have sQL database file in which in a table I have different columns. All column values are in numeric e.g. 1,2,4,12,15, etc. Column 4 is empty. I want to pick a values (one by one) from column-3 and find it in column-2, if it matches in then look in column-1 in the same row and pick value from column-1 and insert it in column-4.

If value of column 3 not matches with column 2 then skip it.

[image]

Find here screenshot to understand exact problem.

Comment: Please add code, errors and data as **text** ([using code formatting](//stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code)), not images. Images: A) don't allow us to copy-&-paste the code/errors/data for testing; B) don't permit searching based on the code/error/data contents; and [many more reasons](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557). In general, code/errors/data in text format >>>> code/errors/data as an image >> nothing.  Images should only be used, *in addition to text in code format*, if having the image adds something significant that is not conveyed by just the text code/error/data.

Comment: In this instance, having your image, *in addition to* the data in text format would be beneficial, because it helps to explain what you want. However, the data in text format should be primary, as it significantly helps for people who are creating answers to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this by joining the table to itself using MySQL `JOIN`

```
UPDATE tbl_name t1
JOIN tbl_name t2
ON t1.column3 = t2.column2
SET t1.column4 = t2.column1;
```

> Output

```
column1     column2     column3     column4
   1          1           2           2
   2          2           3          
   3          5           4         
   4          6           6           4
   5          7           8           6
   6          8          12         
   7         10          11         
   8         14          13         
   9         15          14           8
  10         16          15           9
  11         18          16          10
  12         20          19         
  13         22          20          12
  14         23          25         
  15         24          26
```

Here's the [working example](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/mBeAJBc3pxnXFSnuGkMj5S/0)

Comment: Actually I am new on mysql, I don't know how to write exact query. In example which you provided on row no.8 the values was written manually are automatically obtained?

Comment: Here the query I used, but it only show values not show result in column 4


SELECT `wp_comments`.`comment_post_ID`, `wp_comments`.`ID`, `wp_comments`.`comment_ID`, `wp_comments`.`comment_parent`

FROM `wp_comments`;

UPDATE wp_comments

JOIN wp_comments

ON wp_comments.comment_post_ID = wp_comments.ID

SET wp_comments.comment_parent = wp_comments.comment_ID;

Comment: Run UPDATE query first and then run SELECT query.

Comment: Same Result. Can you start chat so that I will share password of database?

Comment: Share your complete query that your have used by referring to my answer. Don't need DB password for this.

Comment: I want apply to first 4 columns. Comment_ID, ID, comment_post_ID, and comment_parent.

Comment: `UPDATE wp_comments t1
JOIN wp_comments t2
ON t1.comment_post_id = t2.id
SET t1.comment_parent = t2.comment_id;`

This is the query you need to execute. total 310 rows will get updated